# A position is an edge either it's file or rank is an edge. Basics of prolog

Tags: prolog

I've been trying out prolog since yesterday, and trying to define chess rules. In particular, I want to define either a square is an edge or not.

Here are the rules I thought of:

```
 A file is a thru h. 
 A rank is 1 thru 8. 
 A pos is a file and a rank. 
 h is an edge. 
 8 is an edge. 
 A position is an edge either it's file or rank is an edge.
```

I played around, but for example this goes stack overflow. how do I model this?

```
% Prolog %

file(b).
file(a).
file(h).
rank(8).
rank(4).
rank(5).

pos(F, R) :- file(F), rank(R).

edge(h).
edge(8).
edge(X) :- pos(X, Y),!,edge(X),edge(Y).
% I also tried this, but this bloats the space.
% edge(pos(F, R)) :- edge(F),edge(R).

corner(pos(edge, edge)).

%  edge(h). % true
%  edge(8). % true
%  edge(4). % false
%  edge(pos(h, 4)). % true
%  edge(pos(b, 5)). % false
%  edge(pos(b, 8)). % true
%
```

Comment: A more intuitive convention would be e.g. `row_col(1, 2)` - Are you trying to define an edge, or a corner?

Comment: both, having trouble with negation as well, so if you could please define both. an edge is that either file is an edge or a rank is an edge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

basic version:

```
file(a).
file(b).
file(c).
file(d).
file(e).
file(f).
file(g).
file(h).

rank(1).
rank(2).
rank(3).
rank(4).
rank(5).
rank(6).
rank(7).
rank(8).

position(F-R) :-
    file(F),
    rank(R).

edge(a-_).
edge(h-_).
edge(_-1).
edge(_-8).

corner(a-1).
corner(a-8).
corner(h-1).
corner(h-8).
```

then

```
?- corner(C).
C = a-1 ;
C = a-8 ;
C = h-1 ;
C = h-8
```

or positions which have rank > 3 and are edges and are not corners:

```
?- position(X), X=F-R, R > 3, edge(F-R), \+ corner(F-R).  
X = a-4 ;
X = a-5 ;
X = a-6 ;
X = a-7 ;
X = b-8
```

and you can collapse down `file()` and `rank()` rules using `member/2` and `between/2` if desired.

Comment: can you reference what the minus sign is instead of omitting the comma?

Comment: @eguneys as you used in your code here `edge(X) :- pos(X, Y),!,edge(X),edge(Y).` comma already means logical AND so using it for a pair of things clashes. Minus is used to hold a pair in Prolog and that style will work with builtin library code like pairs_keys_values([a-1, b-2], Ks, Vs) and dict_pairs and transpose_pairs and keysort and others. They don't work with `(X,Y)` style. Prolog will never do subtraction unless you explicitly ask for it, so 9-6 is a pair of two numbers and never turns into 3 by itself like in other languages.

Comment: Cool, so does that mean, I can represent pieces on the board like `p*a-4` , as in `pawn at a 4`.

Comment: @eguneys you can and `Piece*File-Rank = p*a-4` will unify. but try some `write_canonical(p*a-4)` and see what the terms are when written in full. That's got this nesting `((p*a)-4)` so it's connecting the piece and rank more closely than the file. Compare to `write_canonical(a-4-p)` which has this nesting `((a,4),p)`. Rank and file together, piece separate. Or `write_canonical(p-(a-4))`.  Some may make your code easier or harder, depending which bits you want to pick out and work with and how many libraries you want to lean on. I guess any will do for learning really.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a good answer, but is a starting point:

```
extreme_pos(1).
extreme_pos(8).

% Requires both Row and Col to be nonvar
pos_edge(row_col(Row, Col)) :-
    (   extreme_pos(Row) -> true
    ;   extreme_pos(Col)
    ).
```